# Getting array input to a variable

Tags: php

I have the following line.

```
$variable = "<tr><td>".$info."</td></tr>";
```

I'm trying to fetch information from a SQL database and attached to `$info` variable. The way I tried fetching from the database is with below.

```
    if(isset($anotherVariable)) {$resultsArray = explode(',', $anotherVariable);}

    if(isset($resultsArray)) {
         foreach($resultsArray as $info):
            ?><li><?= $info ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; }
```

The issue is I'm seeing only a single `<li>` value attached to `$info` as I see the output of `$variable` when printed.

Appreciate your help! I'm also keen to learn if you have an alternative better suggestion/workaround.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. What is the value of $anotherVariable? 
You are assigning explode result to $resultsArray8 but using $resultsArray below.

Comment: @SatishGadhave. Here's what I'm trying to do. Need to get an array output printed at `$info` space. Typically variable values will have an already attached value in situations like `$info` above. I need that `$info` to carry a dynamic value ( series of values) fetched from the database. Fetching is what you see with `foreach`

Comment: Your question is not very clear at all. Please see : [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tigger I did edit the question. Does it make sense now? Thanks

Comment: Are you are sure that resultsArray has more than one value?? If you are only seeing one value there may only be one value stored. Also you setting values into the $resultsArray8 but are looping through the $resultsArray, not the same, is this correct or a typo? Verify you are getting back multiple rows back from database first.

Comment: @javaBean007 yeah, 8 was a typo and corrected. Database has multiple values ;)

Comment: Something is not making sense here, I believe that your line of $variable = "<tr><td>".$info."</td></tr>"; comes after your two if statement checks correct? You are saying that you are looping but only seeing one <li> with one value inside of it? Like others have stated your question is not very clear. Please specify what you are expecting to see AND what you are seeing currently to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to simulate your exact code with below answer.

```
<?php
$anotherVariable = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z";
if(false == empty($anotherVariable)){
    $resultsArray = explode(",", $anotherVariable);
?>
<table>
    <?php 
    if(isset($resultsArray)){
        foreach ($resultsArray as $info) {
            $variable = "<tr><td>".$info."</td></tr>";
            echo $variable;
        }
    }?>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your variable using `if( ! empty($variableResults))` instead of using `isset()`

Try also using `var_dump($your_result)` to check if your result are in the format you are looking for